# JQuery Autocomplete using array as source should display label instead of value on select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomplete and array as source and I want to display the label instead of the value because i am storing the value in a different variable where it is not displayed in the form. But this is what they say in the documentation:

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item.

**Sample images**

Searching:
[image: While searching]

Selecting:
[image: After selecting]

**Codes:**
Array:

```
var searchcustomer_arr = [{label:"ASD CUSTOMER",value:1},
                          {label:"Customer 2",value:2}]
```

Javascript:

```
$("#customer" ).autocomplete({
  source: searchcustomer_arr,
  minlength: 2
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this is working :-

```
$("#customer").autocomplete({
  source:[
          {label:"ASD CUSTOMER",value:1},
          {label:"Customer 2",value:2}
         ],
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#customer").val(ui.item.label);
  }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/phuhnum6/1/)